# else not working (Jquery)

Tags: jquery

I would like to change CSS property by clicking on img using **if** and  **else** function but "else" not working

JQUERY:

```
 $('.expand').click(function(){ callmeman() } );    

function callmeman(){
  if($('.expand').css('background-image') == 'url(img/UP.png)') 
  {
    $('.expand').css({'background-image':'url(img/DOWN.png)'});
  }
  else {
    $('.expand').css({'background-image':'url(img/UP.png)'});
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe it doesn't exactly == ... but aside that, why don't you just use css and toggleClass? You could make up and down.png a single image and just change the background position.

Comment: what about the else doesn't work? Are you certain you have `UP.png` in your img directory? Are you getting any js errors in console?

Comment: Do you have more than one element in your site with class="expand"?

Comment: Also, you should use $(this) instead of $('.expand') in the click function - it will isolate the comparison to just the relevant element

Comment: also try `$('.expand').css("background-image")` in your console (hit f12 in browser), if you notice it should give the fully qualified url not `img/UP.png` so it's probably failing on the equals comparison..

Comment: could it be backgroundImage instead of background-image?

Comment: @ADASein `backgroundImage` would only be if you were using dot notation to access the value in javascript, with the jquery css wrapper  `background-image` suffices.

Comment: could it be then absolute path? easy to check showing alert for bacckground-image.

Comment: I agree with @scrappedcola and @hamism. The path from `.css()` is the full path, and you'll want to adjust your logic when dealing with multiple `.expand` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).  I used background-color, but you can alter to change the background-image.

```js
$('.expand').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
.expand {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.expand.expanded {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="expand"></div>
```

Comment: Yep. Though it would be better with `.up` or `.down`.

Answer (score 0):

When jQuery returns the `background-image`, it's returning it with it's fully qualified name, e.g. `url(http://myurl.com/image/UP.png)`. That's why the first `if` doesn't pass, so it falls back to the `else` and just sets the `background-image` back to `url(img/UP.png)`. As a test you can specify the image with it's fully qualified name and it should work.

The better and more reliable way to do this is using css classes, though. Something like:

CSS:

```
.expand up
{
    background-image: url(img/UP.png);
}

.expand down
{
    background-image: url(img/DOWN.png);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.expand').toggleClass('up').toggleClass('down');
```

Comment: Or use `toggleClass` and simply even further: `$('.expand').toggleClass('up').toggleClass('down');`

Comment: That was what I pointed out. Also when you check for background-color does not return 'black' or '#000' but rgb values and other stuff

Comment: oh thank you all for suggestion I like comments form  **Kai Qing** change the background position. CSS is in folder so in css `background-image: url(../img/UP.png)` maybe **../** why it not working?